# docker - getting my first image to save locally

Tags: docker, jupyter-notebook

I managed to create a docker image and send it up to my repo. It's a Jupyter notebook data science image with qiskit. I can successfully pull the image down with

```
docker pull cfett/chris_repo:qiskit
```

however, when I try to run the image and bind a local volume to save my Jupyter notebooks, I can't seem to save my notebook files. No errors are reported. I'm running the below command, and I see nothing in the file. Am I just making a silly path error somehow?

```
docker run -p 8888:8888 -v /Users/chris/Projects/notebooks:/home/joyvan cfett/chris_repo:qiskit
```

Appreciate any insight!

Comment: Are you running under Linux, Windows, or MacOS?

Comment: MacOS, both on the machine that pushed and on the machine that I'm testing the pull on. OH! I just realized, the machine I pulled on is new apple silicon, while the pushing MacOS was intel. Could that be it??

Comment: Welcome to SO, Could you share the inspect output of the container for mounts i.e. response of `docker inspect --format '{{ index .Mounts }}' <container_id>`

Comment: Thank you for the welcome. :) Here's the output:

`[{bind  /Users/chris/Projects/notebooks /home/joyvan   true rprivate}]`

Comment: When you say that you can't save files, do you mean that the files are not stored in /home/joyvan folder in the container ? 

If so, check the inside the container if the /home/joyvan folder has sufficient permissions to create files

Comment: Hey, I mean that the Jupyter notebook is not saving files in the mapped volume. In this case, after I run the container, open a notebook, create a file, and click save, I do not see that file in the local computer at  /Users/chris/Projects/notebooks . How would I check if /home/joyvan has permissions?

Comment: ran this is docker CLI for the container:
`$ id
uid=1000(jovyan) gid=100(users) groups=100(users)
$ pwd
/home/jovyan
$ ls -lh
total 4.0K
drwsrwsr-x 2 jovyan users 4.0K Jan  2 19:36 work`

Comment: still no luck, though on the pulling machine. I'm not sure why the creating machine can use the image and see host files from within the container while the pulling machine cannot.